# Comparator in template class

Tags: c++

I am working on heap implementation. It has to be template class and I need it to have its own comparator, passed in constructor. How can I do it?

I've tried this:

```
template <typename T>
class Heap{
public:
    Heap(int size, bool (*comparator) (const T & a, const T & b) = [] (const T & a, const T & b){
        return a < b;
    })

    // other unimportant methods
}
```

Which works for:

```
Heap<int> heap(4);
```

And also for:

```
Heap<int> heap(4, [](const int & a, const int & b){ return false; })
```

But when I try to use it with pointers like this (where offer is some structure):

```
Heap<Offer*> heap2(3, [](Offer const * a, Offer const * b){
        return false;
});
```

I got this compilation error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:126:3: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘main()::<lambda(const Offer*, const Offer*)>’ to ‘bool (*)(Offer* const&, Offer* const&)’ [-fpermissive]
  });
   ^
test.cpp:124:59: note: candidate is: main()::<lambda(const Offer*, const Offer*)>::operator bool (*)(const Offer*, const Offer*)() const <near match>
  Heap<Offer*> heap2(3, [](Offer const * a, Offer const * b){
                                                           ^
test.cpp:124:59: note:   no known conversion from ‘bool (*)(const Offer*, const Offer*)’ to ‘bool (*)(Offer* const&, Offer* const&)’
test.cpp:13:5: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘Heap<T>::Heap(int, bool (*)(const T&, const T&)) [with T = Offer*]’
     Heap(int size, bool (*comparator) (const T & a, const T & b) = [] (const T & a, const T & b){
```

How to make it work for both of scenarios?

Comment: Try `Offer* const&` in the parameters of the lambda that is not working.

Comment: Are functors better in some aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the pointer version: 'T' is a pointer then that needs to passed as a const ref - it's not the datum it points to that is to be const qualified here, but the pointer ref itself.

```
template <typename T>
class Heap{
public:
    Heap(int size, bool (*comparator) (const T & a, const T & b)
                                 = [] (const T & a, const T & b){
        return a < b;
    }) {}; 

    // other unimportant methods
};


int main()
{
    Heap<int*> heap2(3, [](int* const& a, int* const& b){
        return false;
    });

    // analogous to  
    Heap<int> heap(4, [](const int & a, const int & b){ 
         return false; 
    });
    // but it's the pointer to the datum in the first,
    // and the datum itself in the latter case
}
```

[live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fcc051f47fccfa5)